# Improving my answer after downvote

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444968/2930477) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444529/how-to-extract-age-from-a-south-african-identity-number-in-c-sharp/30444968#30444968). It contains a solution for the only two fairly reasonable scenarios.

Yet, my answer got a downvote, which was unexpected, so I wonder if anybody might have suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)

Comment: I don't know why your answer was downvoted, but it's not uncommon for answers on low-quality questions to also attract downvotes. If you think the question is worth keeping, consider editing it to improve the question. Good answers on good questions attract upvotes.

Comment: @apaul34208 If there's a point, I'm missing it. I asked how I could improve my answer. After I've read about the keys, I still don't know what I can do better.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That might be it. I've googled that, in fact, and I've seen a post where it's stated that answers should be voted on on their own merits, not in the light of the question. However, I understand there are people... Sigh, those people...   :)

Comment: You could format the code as code, but there's no way to know why someone downvoted, it could have been the question, it could have been the formatting, or it could just be that Tim  lost his keys again.

Comment: Actually I took a look at your profile and it looks like you may have been the victim of some serial voting recently, no way to tell if there's a connection, but you may want to flag that for mod review.

Comment: @apaul34208 Keen eyes, mate. Actually, I've already asked about the serial dump in a different question and learned that there's script running at 3 AM correcting it. However, it appears that not all the serial votes have been corrected. I flagged a mod but nothing came out of that. (I'm almost positive I know who made the serial downvote and why. If I'm right, it's a sad individual, indeed.) And now I'm too afraid to ask again because of a next wave of bullying and bashing.   :(

Comment: Yep looks pretty clear that there were two batches of serial down voting on the 21st but only one was reversed.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't really *answer* the question: the question asks how to determine age given a number that includes birthdate, and you only provided a way to extract the birthdate.

Comment: Birthdate as a string no less, not even as a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to improving your Answer. The OP states that the `9312155886073` is a number, which I would assume is an integer and you expand on them being a String or a DateTime object. So you could expand on starting with an integer specifically as well.
But that kind of detail is hardly the reason for downvote, for me it would be a reason to comment.

As @apaul34208 indicates someone might be after you with serial downvotes. I have experienced the same on U&L together with anyone who rejected suggested edits from one particular user. But those (and your older downvotes) are on questions only, so you cannot really see the suspected downvoter go down in rep. This is on an answer and that falls outside of the other downvotes' pattern.

(For the record, I am not the downvoter).

Comment: The question says the value is in a textbox, so it would be a string.

Comment: Good observation. I still think it's a *String*, though. Social security numbers tend to be non-integers because they are so long (*int* doesn't suffice and *long* is omitted) and because they don't cover the whole range (the first digit of the month is actually a binary number). And I +1'ed you, just so you know.