# Serial voting: reversal problem

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

Yesterday I suffered at the hands of a disgruntled user, who took it upon himself to downvote a number of answers I've posted. It happens.

Today, the script the should sort this out has run, but it's reversed only some of the block of downvotes:

[image]

The four downvotes that have been reversed all occurred at 5:08. Those that occurred at 5:09 remain. We're only talking about 4 rep here, so I'm not going to lose sleep over this one occurrence. However, this seems to be common. On at least two prior occasions serial voting has not been reversed in its entirety.

Some will say that I can't know that all these downvotes were made by the same person. True, but the chances of two answers being downvoted by other users within a minute of a block downvote are, shall we say, vanishingly small.

Is this a problem in the script that could use some attention?

Comment: I dunno...the script's had a pretty good track record of reversals from what I've seen around here.  Do you have any evidence of otherwise?

Comment: @Makoto One possible example (May 21): https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525840/konrad-viltersten?tab=reputation Discussed in the comments here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295237/improving-my-answer-after-downvote

Comment: @makoto Yes - this is it. I could dig around for the previous examples, but thankfully the whole downvoting thing doesn't happen too often so it could take a while.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I had the same a few days ago (May 24): https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123?tab=reputation I got like 4 downV's and 18 upV's. Reversed got 19upV's (1 Too much) and only 3 downV's (1 Too few).

Comment: Hard to say and maybe hard to discuss here. The internals of the script are  secret and so are the votes. Assume they were from 2 users (accounts), what should the script do? I guess it errs on the side of cation.

Comment: The last three downvotes happened at 05:08:58, 05:09:02 and 05:09:08. Assuming that they came from different accounts might be assuming too much in this case...

Comment: In pretty much all cases I have seen the last one or two downvotes are not reversed, so I suspect there's something more to this (looking at other people's accounts here, not my own).