# Is there way to prevent serial voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880916/6214222) which has 12 up and 12 down votes. How is it possible that 12 people downvote and another 12 people upvote? If the answer is good then of course people will up vote. Maybe the user upvoted the answer from different Stack Overflow accounts.

Another [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295434/serial-voting-reversal-problem) suffered at the hands of a disgruntled user, who took it upon himself to downvote a number of answers the author had posted.

Is there any way to prevent serial voting? If someone wants to add fake votes to their post, how can that be prevented?

Comment: There are scripts that detect serial voting. Also, that first answer is old - people literally had years to vote it either up or down.

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear, IMO.  Are you talking asking about how to  preventing fraudulent voting (which includes serial voting) before the vote occurs?  I ask because removing fraudulent votes after the fact is done now and seems to be reasonably successful.  Moderators have a lot of tools to detect this stuff after the fact, but it is hard (impossible?) to stop it beforehand without blocking a lot of legitmate voting

Comment: I don't know anything about Yii2 but it seems to have a comment explaining clearly why the answer might not be a good one.

Comment: _how it is possible that 12 people down vote a answer and then other 12 people up vote the same answer_ easy: take 24 people with opposing views and enough reputation to vote, and show them the answer.

Comment: Dont be confused by this answers downvote/upvote! Jhon has an issue, this simple line of code help him. He upvoted. Jhon's hacker also liked the answer so they upvoted too. People that came to this post without an urgent issue that could be solve by removing their firewall, have downvoted the answer. You're facing a Quality vs Helpfull issue. In real life when people have issue with their kid Killing it is usually a bad advice. For some dev, if it solve the issue it's ok.

Comment: Seems there were serial down-voting on that answer since you asked...

Comment: Look at the user's Reputation tab, Oct 7th 2015.  You can't make too many assumptions when the elves show up to help.  And as usual it is just a waste of effort, SO users will always outnumber elves.  And cheating on rep is boring, such users almost always quit contributing before getting any real rep.

Comment: [You unleashed it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You describe 2 different cases.

The first case is an answer that is controversial. Many people found it helpful, but judging by the comments, many others found it a bad idea. That answer has stood for several years, giving people plenty of time to vote either way.

It is possible for people to have multiple accounts, and use them to vote multiple times. This is called sock-puppetry and it is explicitly forbidden. You *are* allowed to have multiple accounts, but they must not interact - you should not do anything with them that you couldn't do with a single account. So, voting on the same post from multiple accounts is **not** allowed. (Just for the record, I don't think that was what happened on that answer.)

The other case is serial voting. People dislike a user and decide to vote down a lot of their posts. This is forbidden, we should only vote on content, not on the person. There is a script that runs every night at 3.00 AM (UTC), that looks for voting anomalies and reverts the serial voting that it finds. And it probably takes further action against the serial voter, if that is necessary.

Serial voting also works the other way - upvoting a lot of a person's posts because you like that person. This, too, is forbidden. Again, voting should happen only on the content, not on the person.

So - yes, we have automated tools discovering this. Moderators and attentive users also look at it. Sometimes users find suspicious cases and use a custom moderator flag to warn the mods.

Comment: This is really informative for me. I appreciate your answer